# Enviar correo desde mi aplicación web

Tags: php, aplicación-web, email, smtp

Tengo una aplicación web, y he creado una sección de reporte de errores, y me gustaría que los usuarios, cuando tengan un problema, poniendo su correo para poder responderles, puedan escribir sus incidencias y así yo con un correo propio del dominio, poder ayudarles.

He investigado, y de momento no tengo certificado SSL para poder utilizar SMTP del IIS10. Así que voy a utilizar el gratuito de google. ¿Sólo tengo que modificar el archivo php.ini con estos datos?:

```
Servidor (SMTP) de Correo Saliente: smtp.gmail.com
Usar Autenticación: Sí
Usar Conexión Segura: Sí (puede TLS o SSL dependiendo de su cliente de email)
Nombre de usuario: cuenta GMail (email@gmail.com)
Contraseña: contraseña GMail
Puerto: 465 o 587
```

Y otra cuestión. Veo que haciéndolo así, el usuario enviaría el correo con una cuenta de gmail ya establecida. ¿Creo una cuenta de gmail por ejemplo = incidencias@gmail.com? o ¿Hay alguna manera de que los usuarios envien las incidencias con su propio correo?.

---

Luego en el código php tendría que hacer una función tal que así, ¿no?,

```
<?php
 $para      = 'nobody@example.com';
 $titulo    = 'El título';
 $mensaje   = 'Hola';
 $cabeceras = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
 'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

 mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
 ?>
```

Comment: Has pensado en utilizar [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)? A mi siempre me ha funcionado genial.

Comment: Me ha salido en muchas búsquedas relacionadas con el tema! Que tal está esa librería? Es fácil de aplicar y utilizar? @JandroOliva

Comment: Cuando tengo que utilizar envío de emails es la que siempre utilizo. Simplemente tienes que añadirla (te recomiendo usar composser), incluirla y configurar los parámetros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo [PHP MAILER](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Para mi la librería más fácil de usar.

Configuras los parámetros necesarios (tienes múltiples ejemplos) y envías.

Es sencillo y hasta la fecha a mi me ha funcionado muy bien con google.

Comment: Buenas Jandro, he estado probando phpmailer, pero no consigo que funcione. Me da error o no carga. ¿Tendrá algo que ver que uso IIS?

Comment: No te puedo decir, porque yo siempre que monto suelo montar sobre Linux.